# PyQgis Diagram Automated Placement Engine

Tags: pyqgis, diagram

I am trying to programatically change the "Show all labels and features for all layers" option for a layer which display diagrams.

This option doesn't seem to appear in QgsDiagramRendererV2 api.
It seems to be related to QgsPalGeometry, but I can't figure how to set that option so that all diagrams are rendered, even overlapping ones.

Can anybody help on that ?

---

Still no success to turn that option on.
I figured out that it is a global option, and found in QGis api the setShowingAllLabels method in the QgsPalLabeling class.
This is obviously the one I am looking for, but I couldn't manage to make it work :

```
pal = self.iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer().labelingEngine()
pal.setShowingAllLabels(True)
self.iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer().setLabelingEngine(pal)
```

This code doesn't have any effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is the answer :

```
myMapRenderer = self.iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()
mLBL = QgsPalLabeling()
mLBL.setShowingAllLabels(True)
mLBL.saveEngineSettings()
myMapRenderer.setLabelingEngine(mLBL)
```